# Plain button in user control not working with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I had an issue with an ASP button not working properly

This was my button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAgregar" class="tg-btn" runat="server" Text="Agregar a carrito" />
```

And **I solved** the issue using UseSubmitBehavior and data-dismiss as shown below

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAgregar"  UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" class="tg-btn" runat="server" Text="Agregar a carrito" />
```

Well I bumped into another problem similar but I couldn't fix the issue the same way.
Here is my code:

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="providersList" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <button  type="submit" name="provider" class="<%# HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(Item(Of ProviderDetails)().ProviderName) %>" 
            value="<%# HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(Item(Of ProviderDetails)().ProviderName) %>"
            title="Conectate con <%# HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(Item(Of ProviderDetails)().ProviderDisplayName) %> account.">
           Conectate con <%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Item(Of ProviderDetails)().ProviderDisplayName) %>
        </button>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <div class="message-info">
            <p>Acceso por red social suspendido temporalmente</p>
        </div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The result on the client is this:

```
<button type="submit"    name="provider" class="twitter" 
            value="twitter"
            title="Conectate con Twitter account.">
           Conectate con Twitter
        </button>
```

This code **works well** when using it in a plain form but that same code inside a form using Jquery. I tried with the UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" but this doesn't seem to have any effect on that plain button the same it had on the asp button.

Update: I originally thought it was due to bootstrap but after some testing I found out it is jquery which is interfering.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue ! I removed one by one the JS referenced in my project and found this code

```
    jQuery('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Which was causing my button not to behave as expected. Removing this code, part of something I am not using, did the trick.